# Python while-loop for prime number returning unexpected value

Tags: python

I am trying to find the largest prime number in a list (ascending order). I created a while-loop which checks if a number in the list is prime by dividing it by each number less than itself and 'breaking' the loop when it finds a number that has no factor less than itself (greater than 1). This loop is nested in another while-loop which iterates backward through the list.

When I run the code, it keeps returning the number 8 (which is obviously not prime).

I have tried going through the code step-by-step on paper, inserting the variable values and doing the math. I must be miscalculating something.

```
factors = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8]
b = 1
y = len(factors) - 1
x = factors[y]
z = x - b

while y >= 0:
    while b < x:
        if x % z == 0:
            break
        else:
            if b == x-1:
                print(f'The number {x} is the largest prime in the list')
                break #need to end the outer loop here
            else:
                b +=1   
    y -= 1
    b = 1
print('There were no prime numbers in the list')
```

I expect the code to return 'The number 3 is the largest prime in the list'

What it actually returns:

```
The number 8 is the largest prime factor
The number 8 is the largest prime factor
The number 8 is the largest prime factor
The number 8 is the largest prime factor
The number 8 is the largest prime factor
```

Comment: Why do it on paper when you can use `print`s or a debugger?

Comment: Because I am teaching myself and don't know about those options. Do have a suggested resource to get me started?

Comment: add `print(x)` (change `x` to the variable you want) for all variables at the start of each iteration. Anyway, (one of) your problem(s) is that you update `y` and `b` but not `x` on each iteration

Comment: wouldn't x update since it is defined by y?

Comment: once you do `x = factors[y]` it is assigned to a value. Python doesn't know you expect `x` to change when yo change `y`

Comment: Are you sure you want to set `z` to constantly be 7? This means only multiples of 7 are considered in the first modulo check

Comment: In general, you are doing an extensive use of variables, which makes your program unreadable firstly to others, but more importantly to yourself. Since you're iterating over a specific list, you should consider using a `for` loop instead of the outer `while` and that will save you about half the variables

Comment: It looks like you are checking lots of options that you don't need to. Instead of checking if any number lower divides into X, only check if range(2,int(X/2)) divide into the number.

Comment: @MikeSperry If we are going for optimizations, then it will be enough to check until `sqrt(x)` and not `x/2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few main problems with your code:

1. You are not updating the values of `x` (outer loop) and `z` (inner loop) on each iteration. You will want to add for `z`:

```py
else:
    b += 1
    z = x - b
```

and for `x`:

```py
y -= 1
x = factors[y]
b = 1
```

2. The fact that you are having that many variables for that task makes it hard to read and understand. You could for example get rid of `z` all together and simply start `b` from 2 and go up.
3. Since both loops iterate over a known range (outer on the list, inner until `x`) it would be better to use `for` loops instead of `while`. That will also arrange your variables better. For example:

```py
factors = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8]

for number in factors[::-1]:
    for b in range(2, number):
        if number % b == 0:
            break
        elif b == number-1:
            print(f'The number {number} is the largest prime in the list')
            break # you should put this whole code in a function and return here

print('There were no prime numbers in the list')
```

Notice that we don't use any other variables except the ones defined by the loops. That makes the code more readable.

The `factors[::-1]` means we are looping over the list in reverse order.

---

A nice little python feature is adding an [`else` clause on a loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops). This `else` will be executed only if the loop is exhausted without meeting any `break` statement. Which is perfect in our case because if the inner loop is exhausted, then the number is a prime for sure. So it can be:

```py
factors = [2, 3, 4, 6, 8]

for number in factors[::-1]:
    for b in range(2, number):
        if number % b == 0:
            break
    else:
        print(f'The number {number} is the largest prime in the list')
        break # This now breaks the outer loop

else:
    print('There were no prime numbers in the list')
```

Note the use of that same technique also in the outer-loop, as if the inner loop exhausted without hitting the `break` in the `else` block, it means no prime was found so we want to print the no-found message.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation and suggestions. I originally tried using a for loop but I must be off in my code somewhere because it wasn't working as expected. I appreciate all of your example code; I will go back and play around with it myself now.

Comment: @SarahBill You are very much welcome! Happy to help and I hope this will get you on the right track for improving :)

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the below codes please?

```
def prime_numbers(numbers):
    for i in numbers:
        for j in range(2, i):
            if i % j == 0:
                break
        else:
            yield i


try:            
    print(f"{max(prime_numbers([2, 3, 5, 6, 8]))} is the largest prime number.")
except ValueError:
    print("There are no prime numbers in the list.")
```